# Microsoft LifeCam Cinema with Ubuntu 12.04: webcam light blinks, and freezes with guvcview

Tags: webcam, google-talk

I am trying to use my USB Microsoft LifeCam Cinema webcam with Ubuntu 12.04. When not in use, it blinks incessantly and seems to slow down my system. Using google voice or guvcview, the camera works for 5 seconds and then freezes.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: I have a similar problem with the same googletalk-plugin + camera + Chrome. It's a bug so off-topic here but I'm glad I'm not the only one. Firefox works fine for me, try that and don't log in to a Google account in Chrome/Chromium until it gets fixed. Wish I had more info or better advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I filed a bug report today here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/adobe-flashplugin/+bug/1046921

Feel free to add that you are affected by the bug as well so that it hopefully gets fixed sooner rather than later.